# How to intercept headset button press in Android L?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaplayer

My project is almost finished with only one crucial element left. That is what I'm asking right now.

Could anyone tell me how to listen for headset/media button presses in Android L & above? I'm about to attempt using AM.registerReceiver when I realize that it's deprecated and I don't see much documentation/examples in how to use MediaSession (I'm trying to use the compat one since my minSDK is API 16, is there any difference?). Here's what I'm currently doing (which results to nothing):

```
    void initReceivers() throws IllegalArgumentException {
        final int RC = 1001;

        if (!MainActivity.noisyRegistered) {
            app.registerReceiver(noisyReceiver, new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY));
            MainActivity.noisyRegistered = true;

            Intent intent = new Intent(app, AudioReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(app, RC, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            ComponentName name = new ComponentName(app.getPackageName(), AudioReceiver.class.getName());
            MediaSessionCompat mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(app, "sggTag", name, pending);
            mediaSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(pending);
        }
    }

static public class AudioReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON))
            return;
        KeyEvent event = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (event == null || binder == null || player == null)
            return;

        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
                binder.resume();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE:
                binder.resume();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
                if (player.isPlaying())
                    binder.pause();
                else
                    binder.resume();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:
                binder.next();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
                binder.prev();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

My manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".ListenService$AudioReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I'm actually very confused why do I need to provide for a pending intent when there's a setCallback method.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

I recently developed an application which responded to the media button. I tested it in the Samsung Galaxy S II, and it worked.

First, in your AndroidManifest.xml, inside the  area, place the following:

```
 <receiver     android:name="net.work.box.controller.receivers.RemoteControlReceiver" >
<intent-filter android:priority="1000000000000000" >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then, create a BroadcastReceiver in a different file:

public class RemoteControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction()) {
        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent .getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);

        if (event == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intents.ACTION_PLAYER_PAUSE));
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is probably not the best solution out there (specially the hard coded android:priority above). However, it tried a couple of other techniques and none of them seemed to work. So I have to resort to this one... I hope I helped.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html

Use following link also

Comment: Android Studio can't find this part: Intents.ACTION_PLAYER_PAUSE

Comment: n a media playback application, this is used to react to headset button presses when your activity doesn’t have the focus. For when it does, we override the Activity.onKeyDown() or onKeyUp() methods for the user interface to trap the headset button-related events.

However, this is problematic in the scenario we mentioned earlier. When the user presses “play”, what application should start playing? The Music application? The user’s preferred podcast application?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol on 1000000000000000 in my manifest                      Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart and Invalidate and Restart.

This cleared the errors.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html                                                                                                                        Use this link yo can get better solution for that......

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol on 1000000000000000 in my manifest                                1000 must be the higher value for priority, you should get an warning or error pointing that if you use android:priority="1000000000000000". Right thing would be: <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >

Comment: registerMediaButtonEventReceiver is depcrecated

Comment: Where to find the ACTION_PLAYER_PAUSE ? All Intents does not contain it.